# ScalaJS: Referring to non-existent class play.twirl.api.Html

Tags: linker-errors, scala.js, twirl

Tried to upgraded from ScalaJS 0.6.x to 1.3.1. Now I'm stuck with this linking error. It's a play framework cross project where I use twirl templates on client and server side. Here are the configuration files.

I could also reproduce that error with a simple demo:
[play-scalajs-shared-twirl](https://github.com/jorolicht/play-scalajs-shared-twirl)

project/plugin.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-twirl" % "1.5.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-jsdependencies" % "1.0.2")
addSbtPlugin("org.portable-scala" % "sbt-scalajs-crossproject"      % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.portable-scala" % "sbt-scala-native-crossproject" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "1.3.1")
```

and build.sbt:

```
lazy val shared = crossProject(JSPlatform, JVMPlatform)
  .crossType(CrossType.Pure).in(file("shared"))
  .settings(
     commonSettings, 
     name := "shared",
     libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
       "com.lihaoyi" %% "upickle" % "1.2.0"
     )
   )
  .enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin).
    jsConfigure(_ enablePlugins JSDependenciesPlugin ) 
      .enablePlugins(SbtTwirl)
      .settings(
         sourceDirectories in (Compile, TwirlKeys.compileTemplates) +=
         (baseDirectory.value.getParentFile / "src" / "main" / "scala"),
         ...
      )
```

here the error message from compile:

```
[info] Fast optimizing /Users/robert/Workspace/TournService/client/target/scala-2.13/client-fastopt
[error] Referring to non-existent class play.twirl.api.Html
...
[error] There were linking errors
[error] (client / Compile / fastLinkJS) There were linking errors
```

The sbt-Verion is 1.3.5
Any help appreciated - Thanks

Comment: "Now I'm stuck with this linking error." What error? Without that, it's virtually impossible to help you. -- That said, you've got a `%%` dependency on upickle, which should definitely be a `%%%`.

Comment: I get the same error when I put the twirl templates to the client. When I switch back to  ScalaJS 0.6.33 everything is fine. It looks like a linker problem in version 1.1.0 and above . As a ugly workaround I copied the source code of play.twirl.api into my client. Then everything works fine.

Comment: Perhaps the `_sjs1` artifact of twirl is corrupted and doesn't actually contain the relevant `.sjsir` files?

Comment: How can I check the _sjs1 artifact? Is there a CLI distribution of ScalaJS for version 1.1.0 and above?

Comment: You can open a jar like a zip, and see if it contains `.sjsir` files. You can also use the `scalajsp` input task from sbt in your project to see if you can find the given classes on the classpath.